# How can I get a machine type of a Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm running some tests on different Compute Engine instances of various types and I'd like to get a machine type of the instance the testing script is currently running on to distinguish the results.

Is this possible with `gcloud` or some API call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query the metadata server exposed to every Compute Engine VM instance for that.  Running something like

```
wget -q -O - --header Metadata-Flavor:Google metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/machine-type
```

in a VM will print a string like `projects/13236423431/machineTypes/n1-standard-2`.

Comment: In case `wget: unable to resolve host address ‘metadata’` error, one can use the full hostname `metadata.google.internal`, or the IP `169.254.169.254`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the gcloud command to describe the instance:

`$ gcloud compute instances describe <instance> --zone <zone> --format='table(machineType)'`

or the [instances.get](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get) API.